# How to pass pivot table additional columns values using the sync method

Tags: laravel-7

I have  extra columns in my pivot table named number and weight as follows

```
  public function up()
     {
         $schema = static::SCHEMA;
         if (! empty($schema) && (Schema::getConnection()->getDriverName() == 'pgsql')) {
             $schema = $schema.'.';
         } else {
             $schema = '';
        }

    Schema::create($schema.'crime_species', function (Blueprint $table) use ($schema) {
        $table->bigInteger('crime_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('species_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('number')->nullable();
        $table->integer('weight')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('crime_id')->references('id')->on($schema.'crimes');
        $table->foreign('species_id')->references('id')->on($schema.'species');
    });
}
```

I also have a store methods as follows

```
   public function store(array $data = []): Crime
     {
         DB::beginTransaction();

         $item = $this->model::create($data);

    if ($item) {
        $item->fishingMethods()->sync($data['fishingMethods'] ?? []);
        $item->species()->sync($data['species'], ['number'=>4, 'weight'=>20]?? []);
        $item->offences()->sync($data['offences'] ?? []);
        $item->confiscatedItems()->sync($data['confiscatedItems'] ?? []);

        DB::commit();

        return $item;
    }

    DB::rollBack();

    throw new GeneralException(__('There was a problem creating this user. Please try again.'));
}
```

The difficult part which I have encountered is passing extra column values
$item->species()->sync($data['species'], ['number'=>4, 'weight'=>20]?? []); The extra column values 4 for number and 20 for weight were not inserted in the pivot table.

could you help me?

Comment: `['number'=>4, 'weight'=>20]` should be applied to all the elements or to what?

Comment: should be applied to number and weight of the pivot table extra column. If i use just sync($data['species']?? []);the id of crime and species table both inserted in the pivot table. if i add extra columns and use this sync($data['species'], ['number'=>4, 'weight'=>20]?? []); both crime and species id inserted except that the value 4 and 20 are not inserted in the pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table:

```
$item->species()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

**You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:**

```
$item->species()->sync([1 => ['number' => 4, 'weight' => 20]);
```

Note that you have to use a nested array. Where the key of the array is the id of the element to associate and its content the extra columns of your pivot table.

```
$attach = collect($data['species'])->mapWithKeys(function ($specie) {
    return [$specie => ['number' => 4, 'weight' => 20]];
});

$item->species()->sync($attach);
```

Comment: how to implement or apply the concepts stated in the answer provided. would you like to show examples referring to $item->species()->sync($data['species'], ['number'=>4, 'weight'=>20]?? []);

Comment: $data['species'] is a array of species ids attached to $item or crime so in that case should read $item->species()->sync([$data['species'] => ['number' => 4, 'weight' => 20]); please confirm

Comment: No, in this case you would have to iterate ```$data[species]``` one by one. And add them one by one. For convenience, ```attach``` and ```detach``` also accept arrays of IDs as input.